# Get exception instance class name

Tags: java, exception

I would like to know what the exception instance was in this situation:

```
try {
    // some risky actions
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Get instance name there");
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `e.getClass()`? Or what do you mean by *situation* and *instance name*?

Comment: Are you asking for the Exceptions class name? Call ``e.getClass().getSimpleName()`` then.

Answer (score 73):

Here you go:

```java
try {
    throw new ArithmeticException();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println( e.getClass().getCanonicalName()); 
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

Answer (score 20):

The type of the exception is shown as part of the output of:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

To get it programmatically you can use:

```
String exceptionClassName = e.getClass().getName();
```

It is poor form to have logic depending on exception sub types within a catch block. Sonar will flag this as a code violation ([squid S1193](https://github.com/joansmith/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S1193.html)).

Instead you should add multiple catch blocks to catch different types of exceptions:

```
try {
    readFile(fileName);
}
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Error accessing file {}", fileName, e);
}
catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
    LOG.error("Invalid file name {}", fileName, e);
}
```

Note: Since [Log4j 2 (and SLF4J 1.6+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096746/substituting-parameters-in-log-message-and-add-a-throwable-in-log4j-2) you can add a throwable as the last parameter and it will be recognized as such. So the above will work!

Since Java 7 you can also do [a multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html):

```
}
catch (java.io.IOException | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
    LOG.error("Could not read the file {}", fileName, e);
}
```

The benefit of the multi-catch is that you can handle multiple exception types within a single catch block without having to revert to a common super class (like `java.lang.Exception`) that would include exception types you didn't want to handle.

Answer (score 4):

Default exception logging is something like

```
try
{
//
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will print the stacktrace of the exception to system.err

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to add some *contextual information*, you can take a look at **[Apache Commons ContextedRuntimeException](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ContextedRuntimeException.html)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (ContextedRuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getContextEntries());
    }
}

private static void doSomething() {
    int divisor = 0;
    int dividend = 100;
    int result;
    try {
        result = dividend / divisor; // Just throw an exception to test things....
        System.out.print("DIVISION RESULT: "+result);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new ContextedRuntimeException("Oops..division by zero not allowed", e)
        .addContextValue("Divisor", divisor)
        .addContextValue("Dividend", dividend);
    }
}
```

would output:

```
Oops..division by zero not allowed
Exception Context:
    [1:Divisor=0]
    [2:Dividend=100]
---------------------------------
[(Divisor,0), (Dividend,100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [@user1438038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438038/user1438038) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519410/get-exception-instance-class-name#comment52897092_32519410) of this question, you can use `e.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the exception name, for example:

```java
try {
    Double x = 1 / 0; // ArithmeticException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName()) // Will print "ArithmeticException"
}
```

If you want to get `java.lang.ArithmeticException` (to follow our example), you can use `e.getClass().getConicalName()`:

```java
try {
    Double x = 1 / 0; // ArithmeticException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getConicalName()) // Will print "java.lang.ArithmeticException"
}
```