# Substituting parameters in log message and add a Throwable in Log4j 2

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j

I am trying to log an exception, and would like to include another variable's value in the log message. Is there a Logger API that does this?

```
logger.error("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar(), exception);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [ParameterizedMessage](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html)?

From the docs

> Parameters:
>
> messagePattern - The message "format" string. This will be
> a String containing "{}" placeholders where parameters should be
> substituted.
>
> objectArgs - The arguments for substitution.
>
> throwable - A Throwable

e.g.

```
logger.error(new ParameterizedMessage("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar()), exception);
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the above would be expressed as:

`logger.error(new ParameterizedMessage("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar()), exception);`

Answer (score 101):

There is an undocumented feature in Log4j 2 (and [SLF4J 1.6+](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException)).
One can pass `Throwable` as the very last parameter. And it would then get a special treatment.
See [`AbstractLogger#logMessage(String, Level, Marker, String, Object...)`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/c0dee5de75f86eae3e7c272454a4012bfac01cb7/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLogger.java#L2010) and [`ReusableParameterizedMessage#initThrowable()`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/c0dee5de75f86eae3e7c272454a4012bfac01cb7/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ReusableParameterizedMessage.java#L142).

There is no need to bother with `ParametrizedMessage`. The code in the question will work just as expected:

`logger.error("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar(), exception);`