# How to try-catch the actual error instead of hudson.AbortException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using try catch in my jenkins file, to check to see if a specific error is thrown and if it is do certain functionality

```
try {
      // code that throws an error

    } catch (ex) {
      echo 'an error occurred'
      echo "ex: ${ex}"
      if (ex == Exception1) {
         // do stuff
      }

      if (ex == Exception2) {
        // do other stuff
      }
    }
```

My problem is that the error that is being caught is a hudson.AbortException and the message is 'script returned exit code 1'.

How do I catch the actual error that was thrown rather than the hudson/jenkins wrapper?

Comment: `catch(Exception1 e){//work with Exception1}catch(Exception2 e){//work with Exception2}`, etc.. should work

Comment: I don't know what the exception is yet though - I was hoping to print out the exception and find out...

Comment: try something like `println(e.type)` or `e.Type`and you should to be able to see exception type in stacktrace eg. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: `

Comment: Pipelines are groovy, groovy is java "extension" - take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519410/get-exception-instance-class-name

Answer (score 1):

If you are running shell script using  syntax sh script: [echo hello](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)

then you should run it with set +e and set -e, as mentioned in the ref doc. Here set +e and set -e will keep the program running even if you get error in between, which you should handle in shell itself. Returned value will also contain errors if using 2>&1 in shell.

If this returned value contains the Exception you can raise separate error in try itself.

Ex:

```
try{
    def returnedVal = sh script: 'some exception raising code'
    if (returnedVal.toLowerCase().contains('exception1')){
        error("got Exception1")
    }
} catch(Exception ex){
    //handle Exception
}
```

Answer (score -2):

"script returned exit code 1" is actually the error message .
You should check the script you are running and modify it to print the inner script error before exit